# Node.js Memory Issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud

I am very inexperienced when it comes to Node so this may be a simple question. I run a node.js server holding unique Amazon coupons. At peak times I will see hundreds of requests/sec all requesting the coupons which I have stored in a global object. There are typically a couple thousand coupons stored in the one object. It is stored in memory and hosted by IBM's Bluemix.

```
global.coupons['product1'] = ['coupon1', 'coupon2', 'coupon3'];
```

I have been running this server for months and as my requests increase, I have increased allotted memory for the .js server (now up to a max of 3 GB).

Lately the server is losing all the info stored in memory, which returns errors for my users when coupon requests are sent. The last log before memory was wiped is:

```
Detected 1024 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
```

Why is the memory being wiped? This will happen at times when traffic is far less than peak, so I am really unsure the cause.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you running clustered?  `WEB_MEMORY` is a reference to an environment variable that determines how much memory to allocate per cluster.  Run a Google search for `512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY) bluemix` and read some of the articles there.

Comment: A couple of thousand items in memory would not cause you any issues. my bet it is something with how the requests are serviced. also note, that array is probably your worst option for storing data that you want to find later. Use a hash ({}) and fields - as that gets pointer indexed. An array is not indexed in any ways, potentially all requests end up reading through all the items in the array to find A specific item.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like [MongoDB](http://mongoosejs.com/) or [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) which will not load all of the coupons into memory at the same time but be a small bit slower. If this becomes a problem, I'd look into load balancing and the [Node.js cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like, the error you explain, is the result of a problem deeper in the application.

More in detail and due to the fact that this problem occurs far away from request peak it seems like a memory leak. Your app seem to consume more and more memory without giving it back for garbage collection. Once the memory consumption limit is reached the application dies.

I recommend to analyze any endpoint of your application using tools like [apache benchmark](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) or [httperf](https://github.com/httperf/httperf) and analyze where the memory continuos increases.

Once such an endpoint was found check for following items and eliminate those.

- Callbacks and closures
- Leaky constructors of classes you have defined
- Collection objects, such as arrays and hashmaps
- Upstream code

Found in an [article](https://blog.appdynamics.com/nodejs/understanding-node-js-memory-leaks/) which helped me in the past.